# Fligner Wolfe test and 2-sample Wilcoxon test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

What is the significant difference between the Fligner Wolfe test and 2-sample Wilcoxon test?
How can I compare the treatment groups with the control groups of different studies after pooling?